# Can't get Graphql-tools to read my schema.graphql file

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I am using Apollo-server-express and Graphql-tools. I have been all over the Graphql-tools documentation and I can't get this to work. I'm trying to get my schema.graphql file to import as my typeDefs. It seems like Graphql-tools should be making this easy, but something isn't falling into place.

index.js

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const express = require("express");
const { join } = require("path");
const { loadSchema } = require("@graphql-tools/load");
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require("@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader");
const { addResolversToSchema } = require("@graphql-tools/schema");
const app = express();

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    items: (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
      return ctx.prisma.item.findMany();
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    makeItem: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const newItem = context.prisma.item.create({
        data: {
          ...args,
          price: parseInt(Math.ceil(args.price * 100)),
        },
      });
      return newItem;
    },
    deleteItem: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return context.prisma.item.delete({
        where: {
          id: args.id,
        },
      });
    },
  },
};

const schemaSource = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, "schema.graphql"), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schemaSource,
  resolvers,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen(
  { port: 4000 },
  () =>
    console.log(
      ` => Backend server is now running on port http://localhost:4000`
    )
);
```

schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  items: [Item!]!
}

type Mutation {
  makeItem(
    piece: String!
    image: String!
    identifier: String!
    price: Float!
    itemNumber: Int!
  ): Item!
  deleteItem(id: ID!): Item!
}

type Item {
  id: ID!
  piece: String!
  image: String!
  identifier: String!
  price: Int!
  itemNumber: Int!
}
```

In its current state I am getting an error that says: "Error: typeDefs must be a string, array or schema AST, got object"

As I understand it makeExecutableSchema should be doing all the necessary steps, like changing the schema into a string. I can't seem to figure out what is going on here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using babel to transpile your code, I think you can import directly your schema file like: `import yourSchema from "./path/to/yourSchema.graphql";` by the support of the plugin `babel-plugin-import-graphql`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`loadSchemaSync` will load a `GraphQLSchema` object using the provided pointer. You should use `loadTypedefsSync` instead.

```
const sources = loadTypedefsSync(join(__dirname, "schema.graphql"), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});
const typeDefs = sources.map(source => source.document)
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

If you want to use `loadSchema`, you don't need to use `makeExecutableSchema` because your schema has already been created. So you would do this instead as shown in the [docs](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-loading#binding-to-http-server):

```
const schema = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, "schema.graphql"), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const resolvers = {...};
const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
    schema,
    resolvers,
});
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema: schemaWithResolvers })
```

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying use loadTypedefsSync and then pass schemaSource to the new ApolloServer? I have tried that as well without success. I tried loadSchema and loadSchemaSync. I tried addResolversToSchema and passing that to the server. No luck. I keep getting the typeDefs must be a string error.

Comment: If you use loadSchema and addResolversToSchema, you should pass the schema like this: `new ApolloServer({ schema: schemaWithResolvers })`. Please see the edit for additional details.

Comment: I must have a typo or something that I'm not seeing. I commented out all of my code and copied and pasted yours in and it works. But for the life of me I can't see the difference in the code... ha must be something though. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It is worth noting here that addResolversToSchema() requires you to pass "schema". I was passing "sources". It was my understanding that variable names were irrelevant, but that seems to not be the case. That is where part of my problem was coming from.

Comment: Variable names are irrelevant, but in this case you are passing in an object literal, not a variable, and using [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Ahhh right, of course. Thanks for pointing that out.